# Extract words from cell that are exactly 10 characters long and contain number and letter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, text-extraction

I have a list of Lenovo products. I am looking for a way to extract their Product number from it.

The number may sit anywhere in the cell.
The number is 10 characters long, it always contains both numbers and letters and no special characters between them.
Sometimes the number is in brackets or has some special characters before or after (like - _ " < etc.).
I don't need them, I am looking for exactly 10 letters or digits and have at least 1 digit in it.
In the last line from the example there are two words with 10 characters - THINKCENTRE and 12Q6000AGE. THINKCENTRE doesn't contain a number, so it should be excluded.

| Input | Desired result |
| --- | --- |
| LEGION T5 (90SV003WGE) | 90SV003WGE |
| FLEX 5 (82R700BEGE) XKLUSIV | 82R700BEGE |
| V17-IRU 83A2001NGE | 83A2001NGE |
| LENOVO E16 G1 21JT000HGE_WIN 11 | 21JT000HGE |
| LENOVO THINKCENTRE M70T 12Q6000AGE I7-12 | 12Q6000AGE |
| IDEAPAD 3 17ALC6 | 0 or empty |

I tried different formulas but it gives me various results. I managed to find a way to extract the longest word, but very often this number isn't the longest and/or includes a lot of characters for cleanup.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried clearly indicating what problem you are having and the line which produces an error.  Make sure you have removed all on error statements from that code.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: As "THINKCENTRE" is 11 characters then it won't be equal to 10. Which means the test for a number is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting assumptions:

- Substrings of 10 characters only;
- Substrings only contain characters `[A-Z0-9]`
- Contains at least one digit `[0-9]`;
- Contains at least one character `[A-Z]`.

---

**DAF**:

You could try to split your input on anything that isn't alphanumeric. That can be achieved with a double `TEXTSPLIT()` rather easy. Now you can check these substrings against your criteria using some boolean structure. For example:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(s,LET(i,SEQUENCE(36)-1,r,TEXTSPLIT(s,TEXTSPLIT(s,BASE(i,36),,1)),TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(r,ISERR(-r)*(TEXTBEFORE(r&0,i)<>r)*(LEN(r)=10))))))
```

---

**UDF**:

You can also use an UDF applying some regular expression to extract the same as the above:

```
Public Function RegexMatch(s As String) As String

Static RE As Object: If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = "(?:\b|_)(?!\d+\b|[A-Z]+\b)([A-Z\d]{10})(?:\b|_)"
RE.Global = True

Set REMatches = RE.Execute(s)
If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each Match In REMatches
        If RegexMatch = "" Then
            RegexMatch = Match.Submatches(0)
        Else
            RegexMatch = RegexMatch & ", " & Match.Submatches(0)
        End If
    Next
Else
    RegexMatch = vbNullString
End If

End Function
```

The pattern's explaination can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/VX0xXk/1)

You can invoke the UDF using: `=RegexMatch(A2)` or embedded in a `MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(s,RegexMatch(s)))` structure.

Comment: The pattern's explanation really helped, thank goodness they've advanced the automation to that by now ^^. Good idea on excluding the only letters/numbers instead of going with minimum 1 of each and the rest can be either or. A small remark: `REMatches` needs to be declared as an `Object` and `Match` as Variant(?) (got the result this way but don't know if there are more specific declarations for them).

Comment: I believe you are correct in your remarks @Notus_Panda.

Comment: Excellent RegExp pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I am almost sure that there is a clever regular expression for this, but I am not very good at RegEx so I am doing it with plain old VBA. The following function is rather straight forward. It takes a string and

- replaces underscores by space (to handle 21JT000HGE_WIN)
- uses `Split` to get the single words
- loops over all words
- Replace `(` and `)`
- Check for length = 10
- Loop over all characters of a word and check if it contains at least a character and a digit.

You can use that function as UDF in your Excel sheet

```
Function getProductNumber(s As String) As String
    Dim tokens() As String, i As Long
    tokens = Split(Replace(s, "_", " "), " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)
        Dim word As String, j As Long, char As String
        word = UCase(Replace(Replace(tokens(i), "(", ""), ")", ""))
        If Len(word) = 10 Then
            Dim digitFound As Boolean, charFound As Boolean
            digitFound = False
            charFound = False
            For j = 1 To Len(word)
                char = Mid(word, j, 1)
                If Asc(char) >= Asc("0") And Asc(char) <= Asc("9") Then
                    digitFound = True
                ElseIf Asc(char) >= Asc("A") And Asc(char) <= Asc("Z") Then
                    charFound = True
                End If
            Next
            
            If digitFound And charFound Then
                getProductNumber = word
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

`FILTERXML()` can be utilized. For ***Excel-365*** try-

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"(",")","_"," "}))&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')!=.][string-length()=10]"),"")
```

For ***Excel-2013*** and later.

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(",""),")",""),"_"," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')!=.][string-length()=10]"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Or since FILTERXML is limited to Window environment, one could also use `=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"(",")","_"," "}),FILTER(t,(LEN(t)=10)*SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(SEQUENCE(10,,0),t)))*SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),t))),""))`

Comment: Hi Harun, that seems to work pretty well and as expected. How can I add a condition for at least 1 letter in the text as well, as I am getting some only numeric results. :) Thank you!